# If rows has a similar element, keep the shorter row

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe as shown below.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLEUZ.png)

Data for replication:

```
x <- data.frame(cluster=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                groups=c('20000127 20000128',
                         '20000127 20000128 20000134',
                         '20000129 20000130 20000131 20000132',
                         '20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136',
                         '20000128 20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136'),
                chr=c(17,26,35,35,44), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I'm trying to come up with a way to analyze the 'group' column for any groups with similar elements and remove the row with the higher count.

For example,
element 20000128 is present in rows 1,2 & 5. Since row 1 has a lower number of characters, I want to remove rows 2 & 5. I appreciate any help!!

Ideally the end result should only have Cluster 1,3,4. Each element should only appear once. (the clusters with the lowest character count)

Comment: Hi Nico, could you clarify how elements take precedence for removal? Do all elements of group have to appear at least once?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, yes they do

Comment: Consider group 2, which is the shortest group that `20000134` appears in. `20000127` and `20000128` also appear in that group. However, there is a shorter option for `20000127` and `20000128` (group 1). Should you keep both? Is the optimization to create the shortest group for every element, the fewest number of groups or the shortest average group length?

Comment: ideally the end result should have only group 1, 3 and 4. each element should only appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploring this problem has been fun. I've learned that this is a variation of the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and is [NP Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

It would help to understand the scope of your problem. If we are talking 10s of clusters, we could use brute force. If it's thousands of clusters, we are going to have to use an approximation.

I have learned there is an R implementation of the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) in the `RcppGreedySetCover` package.

First we need to convert to two column long form. We can use `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
longx <- x %>% 
    mutate(splitgroups = strsplit(as.character(groups), " ")) %>%
    unnest(splitgroups) %>% select(cluster, splitgroups)
```

Then we can use `greedySetCover` to approximate the smallest set that covers all elements.

```
library(RcppGreedySetCover)
greedySetCover(longx)
#100% covered by 3 sets.
#    cluster splitgroups
# 1:       2    20000127
# 2:       3    20000129
# 3:       3    20000130
# 4:       3    20000131
# 5:       3    20000132
# 6:       5    20000128
# 7:       5    20000133
# 8:       5    20000134
# 9:       5    20000135
#10:       5    20000136
```

This suggests the set of 2,3, and 5 covers everything. But this does not fully answer your question, because, as you know there is a set of clusters that is shorter.

However, what we have learned, is that the minimum set is 3 clusters. Now we can test all combinations of 3 clusters.

```
set.size <- length(unique(greedySetCover(longx)$cluster))
binary.matrix <- table(longx)
combinations <- combn(unique(x$cluster),set.size)

total.lengths <- apply(combinations,2,function(x){
  if(sum(as.logical(colSums(binary.matrix[x,]))) == ncol(binary.matrix))
    {sum(rowSums(binary.matrix[x,]))} 
  else {NA}})

min.length <- min(total.lengths,na.rm = TRUE)
min.set <- combinations[,which(total.lengths == min.length)]
x[min.set,]
#  cluster                              groups chr
#1       1                   20000127 20000128  17
#3       3 20000129 20000130 20000131 20000132  35
#4       4 20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136  35
```

Data

```
x <- data.frame(cluster=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                groups=c('20000127 20000128',
                         '20000127 20000128 20000134',
                         '20000129 20000130 20000131 20000132',
                         '20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136',
                         '20000128 20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136'),
                chr=c(17,26,35,35,44), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Impressive! I wonder in this command: `combinations <- combn(unique(x$cluster), 3)` whether you could (should?) replace the `3` with `set.size`.

Comment: Yes, nice catch. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you both! Quick twist here: say we take clusters 2,3,5 where 20000128 occurs in 2 & 5. How would you go about merging clusters that contain at least one similar element? So the final result only have two clusters where all elements only appear once.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a `while` loop, maybe there's a less loopy solution...

```
foo <- function(x) {
  i <- 1
  while(i < nrow(x)) {
    grps <- strsplit(x$groups, " ")
    keep <- unlist(lapply(grps, function(x) identical(x, grps[[i]]) | !any((length(x) > length(grps[[i]]) & duplicated(c(grps[[i]], x))))))
    x <- x[keep,]
    i <- i+1
  }
  x
}

foo(x)
  cluster                              groups chr
1       1                   20000127 20000128  17
3       3 20000129 20000130 20000131 20000132  35
4       4 20000133 20000134 20000135 20000136  35
```

---

Explanation.

```
# I created a function to keep things compact and allow it to be used for other datasets. 
# The `x` is the argument, assumed to be your data frame.
# 1: foo <- function(x) {

# Start the ball rolling with a counter to use in the while loop.
# 2: i <- 1

# This starts the while loop and will continue until "i" reaches the end of the data. 
# But note later that the data may change if there are rows that meet your condition.
# 3: while(i < nrow(x)) {

# Split the groups variable at the " " and store in "grps"
# 4: grps <- strsplit(x$groups, " ")

# This next line does the work. 
# It creates a vector of logical indices which are used to remove rows of "x"
# I split this into many lines to explain better.

# 5: keep <- unlist(lapply(grps, function(x) # apply a function to "grps"
#     identical(x, grps[[i]]) |  # Returns TRUE for each row we are checking
#     !any(  # Negate the next conditions. They will return rows to remove.
#         (length(x) > length(grps[[i]]) & # return TRUE (negated=FALSE) if the length of each x is more than all others
#         duplicated(c(grps[[i]], x))))))  # if duplicated, return TRUE (negated=FALSE)

# Update "x" by keeping only the rows that meet the criteria defined in step 5.
# 6:    x <- x[keep,]

# Increase i
# 7:    i <- i+1
# 8:  } # This ends the while loop
# 9:  x # Return the result
} # End of function
```

Comment: Hi, this somehow works but I'm trying to understand the function. Could you please explain what its doing? I can't figure out how its working